# Get product color in color filter by Category wise

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to get a specific category products by category slug.I have Color model,Product model and product variation model in shop app.

```
class Colour(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    color_code = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
```

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/products')
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="procat")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField()
```

```
class ProductVaraiant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Colour,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    amount_in_stock = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['product', 'color', 'size','brand'],
                name='unique_prod_color_size_combo'
```

In my views.py,

```
def shop(request,category_slug=None):

    categories = None
    products = None
    if category_slug != None:
        categories = get_object_or_404(Category,slug = category_slug)
        products = Product.objects.filter(category=categories,is_available=True).order_by('id')
        variation = ProductVaraiant.objects.filter(product__category = categories)
        print(variation)
        # color = color.objects.all()
        products_count = products.count()
    else:
        products = Product.objects.all().filter(is_available=True).order_by('id')
        products_count = products.count()
        variation = ProductVaraiant.objects.all()
        print(variation)

    context = {
        'products' : products,
        'products_count' : products_count,
        'variation' : variation
    }
    return render(request,'shop/shop.html',context)
```

my category model,

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self',blank=True,null=True,related_name='children',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    category_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/categories',blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def img_preview(self): 
        return mark_safe('<img src = "{url}" width = "50" height = "50"/>'.format(
             url = self.category_img.url
         ))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['category_name']
```

what i am trying to get is like i have 3 child category..Each category will have product of any color.So,if i filter product by category,color will be shown in sidebar of that category products without avoid getting duplicates as many product may have same color.So,i am getting same color multiple times.If i need to use distinct(),how to use it in query that will remove duplicate color based on product category.I tried this in template

```
                <form>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-3">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" checked id="color-all">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="price-all">All Color</label>
                        <span class="badge border font-weight-normal">1000</span>
                    </div>
                    {% for i in variation %}
                    {% ifchanged i.color %}
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-3">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input filter-checkbox" id="{{i.color.id}}" data-filter="color">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{i.color.id}}">{{i.color}}</label>
                        <span class="badge border font-weight-normal">150</span>
                    </div>
                    {% endifchanged %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </form>
```

But,it just remove duplicate of last iteration.How to avoid getting duplicates for all color?

Answer (score 0):

Just where you have a line
`# color = color.objects.all()`
change it to `color = variation.color.all().distinct('id')` and then pass it to your template.

Comment: Not working.Please kindly see the model relationship again.as in your query,color is not in my product model but in variation model.So,i have to get color and product by category based on those color from variations

Comment: try now, miscopied model name for the first time. Also a get idea will be not to display full list of colors related to all of the products, but only to the specific one on specific product page.

Comment: May be i need to be more specific with an example.I have a category with sub categories.Each subcat have different types of product and color.I want to get the color list when i enter the url(localhost/store/sub-cat-name).Color list will be based on subcategory products not of all products.I want to do that because when i have more than 10 color's of products,it will look messy in UI and i don't want to show color's where there is no products of that color in subcategory.From my code,i did that with variation but as each variation product can have same color,i am getting duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Answer of my problem,
what i did:

```
variation = ProductVaraiant.objects.filter(product__category = categories)
```

what i changed:

```
variation = ProductVaraiant.objects.filter(product__category=categories).values('color__title').distinct()
```

if using postgre database,don't need to use values,just use distinct('color') and you will need to use values for default database to avoid error below,

```
DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend
```